# Mapping between two objects that contain a List using Orika

Tags: java, list, mapping, orika

I am trying to use Orika to map between two objects that contain a `List<...>` where the List type is another object, however despite trying various permutations of the mapping configuration in `mapperFactory.classMap(...)` Orika throws an exception when I run my program.

Looking at http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/mappings-via-classmapbuilder.html it seems to suggest that that syntax for mapping a `List` should be `parentProperty{childProperty}`.

For the purposes of this question I've simplified the objects that I'm trying to map. The source object is `ToDoTaskListEntity` and the destination object is `ToDoTaskListDTO`. The source object `ToDoItemEntity` contains a List which is defined as `List<ToDoItemEntity>` and the destination object contains a corresponding List which is defined as `List<ToDoItemDTO>`

**My question is** how should I define the mapping configuration in Orika between `ToDoTaskListEntity` and `ToDoTaskListDTO` so that the child object `List<ToDoItemEntity>` is also mapped to `List<ToDoItemDTO>` within their respective parent objects?

---

The code for my mapping configuration is as follows:

```
MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

mapperFactory.classMap(ToDoItemEntity.class, ToDoItemDTO.class)
    .field("id", "id")
    .field("description", "description")
    .field("status", "status")
    .byDefault()
    .register();

mapperFactory.classMap(ToDoTaskListEntity.class, ToDoTaskListDTO.class)
    .field("listName", "listName")
    .field("toDoItems{id}", "toDoItems{id}")
    .field("toDoItems{description}", "toDoItems{description}")
    .field("toDoItems{status}", "toDoItems{status}")
    .byDefault()
    .register();
```

The code for invoking the mapping is as follows:

```
MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
ToDoTaskListDTO toDoTaskListDTO = mapper.map(toDoTaskListEntity, ToDoTaskListDTO.class);
```

The code for my source objects is as follow:

```
public class ToDoTaskListEntity {

    private String ListName;
    private List<ToDoItemEntity> toDoItems;

    // Getters and setters
}

public class ToDoItemEntity {

    private int id;
    private String description;
    private Status status;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

The code for my destination objects is as follow:

```
public class ToDoTaskListDTO {

    private String listName;
    private List<ToDoItemDTO> toDoItems;

    public ToDoTaskListDTO(String listName, List<ToDoItemDTO> toDoItems) {
        this.listName = listName;
        this.toDoItems = toDoItems;
    }

    //Getters but no setters

}

public class ToDoItemDTO {

    private int id;
    private String description;
    private Status status;

    public ToDoItemDTO(int id, String description, Status status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.status = status;
    }

    // Getters but no setters
}
```

The exception that thrown by Orika is as follow:

```
Exception in thread "main" ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: exception while creating object factory for test.orikademo.ToDoTaskListDTO
-----begin dump of current state-----------------------------
Registered object factories: 1 (approximate size: 25.4 kB)
  [ToDoTaskListDTO] : {}
-------------------------------------------------------------
Registered mappers: 2 (approximate size: 961.5 kB)
  [0] : GeneratedMapper<ToDoItemEntity, ToDoItemDTO> {usedConverters: [], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [], usedTypes: [] }
  [1] : GeneratedMapper<ToDoTaskListEntity, ToDoTaskListDTO> {usedConverters: [], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [DefaultBoundMapperFacade<ToDoItemEntity, ToDoItemDTO>], usedTypes: [List<ToDoItemEntity>, List<ToDoItemDTO>] }
-------------------------------------------------------------
Registered concrete types: 5 (approximate size: 122.4 kB)
  [interface java.util.List] : ArrayList<Object>
  [interface java.util.Set] : LinkedHashSet<Object>
  [interface java.util.Collection] : ArrayList<Object>
  [interface java.util.Map$Entry] : MapEntry<Object, Object>
  [interface java.util.Map] : LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>
-------------------------------------------------------------
Resolved strategies: 0 (approximate size: 0.8 kB)
-------------------------------------------------------------
Unenhance strategy: ma.glasnost.orika.unenhance.BaseUnenhancer@292a74d5
-----end dump of current state-------------------------------
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.ObjectFactoryGenerator.build(ObjectFactoryGenerator.java:110)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.lookupObjectFactory(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1005)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.lookupObjectFactory(DefaultMapperFactory.java:925)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.resolveMappingStrategy(MapperFacadeImpl.java:218)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:734)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:714)
    at test.orikademo.App.main(App.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.ObjectFactoryGenerator.addSourceClassConstructor(ObjectFactoryGenerator.java:173)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.ObjectFactoryGenerator.addCreateMethod(ObjectFactoryGenerator.java:124)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.ObjectFactoryGenerator.build(ObjectFactoryGenerator.java:95)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted the same question in the [Orika discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orika-discuss/2CA6I9nILFk) on Google Groups and got the following answer from Sidi Mohamed which solved my problem.

> You do not need any specific mappings for this example, the only issue
>   I can see here is the  non default constructor on the DTO side
>
> ```
> MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
> // item class map
> mapperFactory.classMap(ToDoItemEntity.class, ToDoItemDTO.class)
>     .constrcutorB("id", "description", "status")
>     .byDefault()
>     .register();
>
> mapperFactory.classMap(ToDoTaskListEntity.class, ToDoTaskListDTO.class)
>     .constructorB("listName", "toDoItems")
>     .byDefault()
>     .register();
> ```
>
> To answer your question the expression like toDoItems{id}  is used
>   only to project (or flatten) your objects, in this example what you
>   want is to re use your previous mapping definitions (eg. reuse item
>   class map when mapping toDoItems in the second class map)  which why
>   Orika is used :  to reduce the boilerplate code.